# Impact of time between salad preparation and consumption

Tags: nutrition

Will a salad made with cut spinach, grated beetroot and carrot, mixed with curd/yogurt, kept in refrigerator retain it's nutrients 1 hour after the preparation?

Only thing I know that upon cutting iron in the vegetables starts oxidising and vegetables look dark in colour, but I can't make out the difference in colour.

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on the cooking exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another stack exchange site, however it cannot be migrated (And possibly get better answers) since it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting and storing vegetables for an hour in the refrigerator would likely have only a negligible effect on their nutrient content. There could be a considerable change in the look and taste, though.

[Quality Changes and Nutrient Retention in Fresh-Cut versus Whole Fruits during Storage, 2006 (Journal of Agricultural and Food Chemistry)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jf060303y)

> Fresh-cut pineapples, mangoes, cantaloupes, watermelons, strawberries,
>   and kiwifruits and whole fruits were stored **for up to 9 days** in
>   air at 5 °C.
>
> Contrary to expectations, it was clear that **minimal processing had
>   almost no effect on the main antioxidant [vitamins A, C and E, and
>   polyphenols] constituents.**